# Overflow text after it takes up certain amount of screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have text overflow down once it has taken up 80% of it's DIV. I'm wanting the dots to take space between the item name and price. However when the item name is too long it cuts of the words. I would like the words to wrap or flow down. I cant seem to figure out how to do this.

Here is an example of the issue: See the 3rd item and how it get's cut off.

https://jsfiddle.net/x4t2hc0o/2/

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.descripcion {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.descripcion:after {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  content: " ........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................."
}
#name {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h4 class='descripcion'> <span id='name'>Burger</span> </h4>
  <h4 class='precio'> $9.99 </h4>
</div>



<div class="item">
  <h4 class='descripcion'> <span id='name'>Hot Dog</span> </h4>
  <h4 class='precio'> $4.99 </h4>
</div>



<div class="item">
  <h4 class='descripcion'> <span id='name'>Much longer item name that ends up taking too much of the space and going outside of the div</span> </h4>
  <h4 class='precio'> $4.99 </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: What do JavaScript and jQuery have to do with this?

Comment: Not sure if it can be solved using either.

Comment: Maybe?? --> https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/x4t2hc0o/4/

Comment: Not bad @Scott! It's pretty close. A little clunky. This is a model of what I'm after. http://www.spice-affair.com/menu/

Comment: Yeah it's not exactly "elegant' but seems like it would get the job done. Is that link yours or did I just happen to come up with a very similar solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is to use a center flex container that grows, and allow h4 tags to wrap by default....

This would require some additional alteration for specific uses, but overall the theory may work.

```css
.item {
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
 
  
}
.descripcion {
  overflow: hidden;

}

span.dots { flex-grow: 1; min-width: 10%;height: 35px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; border-bottom: 2px dotted #aaa;}

#name{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">     
<h4 class='descripcion'> <span id='name'>Burger</span> </h4>
<span class="dots"></span> <h4 class='precio'> $9.99 </h4>
 </div>

 

 <div class="item">     
<h4 class='descripcion'> <span id='name'>Hot Dog</span> </h4>
 <span class="dots"></span><h4 class='precio'> $4.99 </h4>
 </div>

 
 
 <div class="item">     
<h4 class='descripcion'> <span id='name'>Much longer item name that ends up taking too much of the space and going outside of the div</span> </h4>
 <span class="dots"></span><h4 class='precio'> $4.99 </h4>
 </div>
```

Comment: Very cool Scott. I've been playing with trying to make the dots connect on the 3rd option. Any thoughts?

Comment: any thoughts on above?

Comment: Wait nevermind I removed   margin-right: 5px; and it did the trick :)

Comment: Oh yeah.. I added the margin to give a bit of breathing room to the dots... but it can easily be removed :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your name id's to classes as there's more than one.
If a jQuery version is acceptable here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/ggbysn3s/
In this version the width of the `.name` class is checked relative to it's parent, and then the `.descripcion` class is swapped for a new `.wrapped` class. the :after

There's an additional bit of jquery to reposition the price but the dots are missing in this version